# Get files and folders from Sharepoint using REST aPI

Tags: sharepoint

I can get files and folders from Sharepoint site using my office365 account. I just browse to the url and download the folders/files.

My question is: Is it possible to use the same account info to get those same files and folders using REST API, or theRESP API endpoint require additional security? I ask this because most examples I found uses oAuth.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you tried access folder form your external application?

If external application you can use oauth In Oauth how you maintain the configuration part like client id client secrets and your JS file need to be minified then only it secured from browser,

If you are inside the SharePoint you are able to access the REST API after only successful authentication.

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You must use OAuth.  Even when you browse there you are using OAuth/Azure/SSO behind the scenes.  The browser just takes care of it behind the scenes.